# Clearing fields after the validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 date textboxes with a compare range validator. When I choose the wrong dates I get a red flag like expected from the validator but the date textboxes are not reset to empty with the clear button logic after the red flag alert. It does not hit the break point in the Clear_Click if there is a red flag. Please help.

aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FromDate" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="ToDate" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="DateCompareValidator" ControlToCompare="FromDate"
     ControlToValidate="ToDate" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ErrorMessage="*Invalid date range - Please check"
     runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>

<asp:Button ID="ClearButton" Text="Clear" runat="server" OnClick="Clear_Click"/>
```

CodeBehind .cs:

```
protected void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FromDate.Text = String.Empty;
  ToDate.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: It's for the Clear Button, clear button will clear all the fields including the date fields. I will not reset to empty just because it was typed in wrong, it's only when someone wants to start over with the form and clean all the fields and if the validation error occurs it's not going to the code behind for clear_click

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Perhaps you should have left out the part about validation. It's not really relevant. You want to be able to clear the fields even if there has not been a validation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to clear the TextBox, i would not do a postback to the server. I would use simple `JavaScript` with or without jQuery. For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FromDate" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="ToDate" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="DateCompareValidator" ControlToCompare="FromDate"
     ControlToValidate="ToDate" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ErrorMessage="*Invalid date range - Please check"
     runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>

<input type="button" id="clearButton" value="Clear" />

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#clearButton" ).click(function() {
  $("#<%= FromDate.ClientID %>").val("");
  $("#<%= ToDate.ClientID %>").val("");
});
});
</script>
```

Here is a very small example (without asp.net controls):

```js
$(function() {
$( "#clearButton" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#FromDate").val("");
  $("#ToDate").val("");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input ID="FromDate" type="text" />
<input ID="ToDate" type="text" />

<input type="button" id="clearButton" value="Clear" />
```

**EDIT:**

1. If you click the buttons, does `Clear_Click` really get fired?
2. In my test every think works perfect, look at the following example:
   ASPX:

   ```
           <asp:Button ID="ClearButton" Text="Clear" runat="server" OnClick="Clear_Click" />
       </div>
   </form>
   ```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ButtonTest2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FromDate.Text = String.Empty;
            ToDate.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Is you code similar to mine?

Comment: Thanks BendEg, I tried this but it didn't work. Is there any way to do this from codebehind?

Comment: @Namekal done, please compare your code with my code, hope it helps :)